# ASP.NET to call my method every hour

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to send email remainder. I created a method that will send emails to the users that have an appointment in the next hour. Right now i have to call my method manually. But i want to use HangFire( or if you have a better suggestion) to call my method every hour( 3:00 PM, 4:00 PM, and so on). I don't want to use Windows task scheduler because i won't have access to the server in the future.

```
  //[HttpPost("lll/reminder")]
    public IActionResult EventReminder()
    {
        var date = DateTime.Now;
        var events = eventRepository.GetEventsByDateTimeNow();
        foreach(Event evnt in events)
        {
            var usr = userRepository.GetUserById(evnt.AttendeeId);

            var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("", ""));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("User", usr.Email));
            message.Subject = "Remainder";
            message.Body = new TextPart("html")
            {
                Text = "message"

            };
            using (var client = new SmtpClient())
            {
                client.Connect("smtp.gmail.com", 587, false);
                client.Authenticate("", "");

                client.Send(message);

                client.Disconnect(true);
            }               
        }
        return Ok();
    }
```

This is the method. It's working but i have to call it manually. So, any ideas?

Comment: Check this out. https://github.com/kevincolyar/CronNET

Comment: Have you looked at Quartz.NET? It is a nice way of scheduling your jobs. You can find some details on their page: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

Comment: Quartz, Hangfire like you suggested, this is not a very good question. You are asking for tools really.

Comment: For simple things like this I really recommend to write a simple windows service. With topshelf you are up and running within minutes.

Comment: Hangfire is an excellent choice, and does exactly what you need. Documentation on their site is very good, and it's easy to set up. What is your exact question here? Just go ahead and implement Hangfire. If you run into issues, then you can ask *specific* questions about those.

Comment: Thanks guys for the quick answers.  I asked because i wasn't so sure about what to use. I only knew about Hangfire. This is the first time when i try to do a method to run in background.  The documentation for both, Quartz and Hangfire , are indeed explicit. I rushed a bit with the question. I will look into windows service as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've already mentioned, HangFire can help you with this. [They have several examples directly on their home page.](https://www.hangfire.io) The one you want is probably the 'recurring job':

> **Recurring jobs**
>
> Recurring jobs fire **many times** on the specified **CRON schedule**.
>
> ```
> RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
>     () => Console.WriteLine("Recurring!"),
>     Cron.Daily);
> ```

You can setup and configure hangfire a variety of ways, but the most simple is to simply add it to your Startup.cs file.

I'd recommend you [follow the quick start guide,](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/quick-start.html) since your use case appears fairly straight forward, running the 'server' in the web app is probably good enough for many small sites/apps and use cases.

[There are ways to help improve running the server in the web app itself.](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html) That said, if you need something extremely robust, [setting up the 'server' as a Windows Service or other 'out of process' process](http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-processing/placing-processing-into-another-process.html) is probably time well spent and something hangfire easily supports as well.

Comment: Thanks! That will do. I will try to implement it now.

Comment: Good luck. I've been using it in production (with the out of process server) and it works really well. The dashboard is a nice touch too for monitoring whats going on.